# How to exclude images from Plone navigation tree by default

Tags: plone

I notice that if I make a page and add and upload an image to include in it, by default it is included in the site navigation. How can I stop this from happening automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**

There is a Plone setting which tells which types are included in the navigation. Go to ZMI > portal_propeties > navtree_properties > metaTypesNotToList and add *Image* there.

**Option 2**

For each image, toggle checkbox "Exclude in navigation" on Image's Settings tab.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to do so on a container basis, you could use the content rule included in [sc.contentrules.metadata](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sc.contentrules.metadata).

just add it to your buidout and configure it manually to set the **ExcludeFromNav** field to **True**.

an alternate way to do so is to include a **contentrules.xml** in your project profile with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contentrules purge="True">
 <rule name="exclude-on-add" title="Images are excluded from navigation when added"
    description="" enabled="True"
    event="zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent"
    stop-after="False">
  <conditions>
   <condition type="plone.conditions.PortalType">
    <property name="check_types">
     <element>Image</element>
    </property>
   </condition>
  </conditions>
  <actions>
   <action type="sc.contentrules.actions.ExcludeFromNav">
    <property name="exclude">True</property>
   </action>
  </actions>
 </rule>
 <assignment name="exclude-on-add" bubbles="True" enabled="True" location="/your-container"/>
</contentrules>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the options for `Navigation`in the `Site Setup` menu.
Remove the tick on image for displayed content types and images are not longer shown on site navigation and site maps.